# is it possible to get the uid of peer of socket with local AF_INET and AF_INET6

Tags: sockets

Is it possible to get the uid of peer of socket with local AF_INET and AF_INET6, i would like to authenticate with this info.

I learned that it is possible to local socket, but not sure whether local AF_INET and AF_INET6 is ok, please help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this with any of AF_INET sockets. Just think about it - they might be coming from a system where uuid simply does not exist :)

Comment: Thanks Remy & SergeyA, got that we cannot get uid directly. Another question is: is there a way in Linux system (for example: /proc) to get the answer? I am wondering whether there is a map between port (123456) and browser (chrome) in below case: 192.168.1.1:123456 (Chrome)  <===> www.google.com

Comment: Not sure I got the question. If you want to know which process opened specific socket port, you can do lsof - but of course, you need to run it on the machine where the process is executed.

Comment: Yes, it is the question. I just modified from netcfg source to get the port/uid mapping in my program.  Thank you ：）

Comment: @smart, feel free to upvote/accept my answer than :)

Comment: sorry, just saw the msg. thanks a lot for the answer, but saw below msg, can you let me know how to handle below error? "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

IP sockets do not have UIDs, only IP addresses and ports.